# Retrieve from a list of directory in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have some disk snapshots in GCP and I can get them in a list:

```
snap_list:
  - name: s-1-data-2022-01-01
  - name: s-1-data-2022-02-01
  - name: s-1-data-2022-03-01
  - name: s-2-data-2022-01-01
  - name: s-2-data-2022-02-01
  - name: s-2-data-2022-03-01
  - name: s-3-data-2022-01-01
  - name: s-3-data-2022-02-01
  - name: s-3-data-2022-03-01
```

s-1, s-2 and s-3 are servers.

I want to create a Ansible playbook that will retrieve the latest snapshot(from 2022-03-01) for each server and then create the disk with that snapshot, then attach to the server.

How do I pick up the latest snapshot for each server from the snap_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Retrieve the latest snapshot for each server."***

A: For example, declare the variables below as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

```yaml
_snap_lst: "{{ snap_list|
               zip(_srv_date)|
               map('flatten')|
               map('combine')|list }}"
_srv_date: "{{ snap_list|
               map(attribute='name')|
               map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|
               map('from_yaml')|list }}"
_regex: '^(.*)-data-(.*)$'
_replace: '{"server": "\1", "date": "\2"}'
```

gives

```yaml
  _snap_lst:
    - {date: '2022-01-01', name: s-1-data-2022-01-01, server: s-1}
    - {date: '2022-02-01', name: s-1-data-2022-02-01, server: s-1}
    - {date: '2022-03-01', name: s-1-data-2022-03-01, server: s-1}
    - {date: '2022-01-01', name: s-2-data-2022-01-01, server: s-2}
    - {date: '2022-02-01', name: s-2-data-2022-02-01, server: s-2}
    - {date: '2022-03-01', name: s-2-data-2022-03-01, server: s-2}
    - {date: '2022-01-01', name: s-3-data-2022-01-01, server: s-3}
    - {date: '2022-02-01', name: s-3-data-2022-02-01, server: s-3}
    - {date: '2022-03-01', name: s-3-data-2022-03-01, server: s-3}
```

Then, [*grupby*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby) the attribute *server* and, in the loop, [*sort*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.sort) by the attribute *date*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "server: {{ item.0 }}, snapshot: {{ _latest.name }}"
      loop: "{{ _snap_lst|groupby('server') }}"
      vars:
        _latest: "{{ item.1|sort(attribute='date')|last }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'server: s-1, snapshot: s-1-data-2022-03-01'
  msg: 'server: s-2, snapshot: s-2-data-2022-03-01'
  msg: 'server: s-3, snapshot: s-3-data-2022-03-01'
```

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for the reply. I am not sure how to make your first part of the code working. I tried to copy it into my playbook and got a syntax error. Sorry I am pretty new to Ansible.

Comment: Okay I used "- set_fact" to include the first part of the code and it worked. Thanks Vladimir!

Comment: Make sure you understand the [precedence of variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) if you are new to Ansible. It's very important to move forward. You're welcome!